# Use MS Excel to round one number to 2 significant figures, then update another cell to match the number of decimal places

Tags: excel, rounding, matching

I am trying to use Microsoft Excel to format a large set of data. The data is all in decimal format and the results are paired so that we have 2 values per record. The first value is a Mass in grams, and the second value is the Uncertainty of that mass also in grams.

For example: 
SampleName = S1, Mass(g) = 28.695,  Uncertainty(g) = 1.601133

What I need to do is have the "Uncertainty" update to 2 significant figures, then depending on the value returned, have the "Mass" update to match the number of decimal places (or whole numbers) that the "Uncertainty" now is.

e.g.

- if Uncertainty became 1.6, then Mass should become 28.6
- if Uncertainty became 1.61, then Mass should become 28.69
- if Uncertainty became 2, then Mass should become 29

I have attempted to use the ROUND function on the "Uncertainty" cell but then I don't know how to make the "Mass" cell update accordingly.

I have tried the following 2 ROUND formulas, which both seem to work for rounding the "Uncertainty":

=ROUND(A1,2-INT(LOG(ABS(A1))))

=ROUND(A1, 2)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, I wrote that in haste

Answer (score 0):

This formula counts the number of decimal places in a given cell:

`=LEN(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)))`

So you could use this in your Round formula where you specify the number of decimals:

`=ROUND(A1, LEN(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1))))`

Answer (score 0):

To round to 2 significant figures you can use something like this:

```
=ROUND(uncertainty,2-(1+INT(LOG10(ABS(number)))))
```

To round (eg) B2 based on number of decimals in (eg) D2:

```
=ROUND(B2,IFERROR(LEN(RIGHT(D2,LEN(D2)-FIND(".",D2))),0))
```

[image]